# How to run a script in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to run a script in the pyspark environment but so far I haven't been able to.

How can I run a script like `python script.py` but in pyspark?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can do: `./bin/spark-submit mypythonfile.py`

Running python applications through `pyspark` is not supported as of Spark 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you tell me how to do it in Windows?

Comment: @DanielRodríguez Should be the same. The spark folder you downloaded should have a `spark-submit` file

Comment: It tells me that 'sc' is not defined, and when I run spark-submit after opening pyspark it throws an invalid syntax error

Comment: It sounds like you are haven't initialized an 'sc' variable with SparkContext(). Take a look at this page, if you haven't already done so https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/python-programming-guide.html. It's hard to tell what you might be doing wrong without seeing your code.

Answer (score 33):

pyspark 2.0 and later execute script file in environment variable `PYTHONSTARTUP`, so you can run:

```
PYTHONSTARTUP=code.py pyspark
```

Compared to `spark-submit` answer this is useful for running initialization code before using the interactive pyspark shell.

Comment: i dont understand the instructions on what to do here. how do I do your instructions?

Comment: Works as a charm. @Dr.DOOM Just type in your shell

Comment: This is totally a misleading and wrong answer. Just because "It works", It doesn't mean you should do that. @Ulas Keles answer is the correct one

Answer (score 21):

Just `spark-submit mypythonfile.py` should be enough.

Answer (score 15):

You can execute "script.py" as follows

```
pyspark < script.py
```

or

```
# if you want to run pyspark in yarn cluster
pyspark --master yarn < script.py
```

Comment: Why are you using shell redirection?

Comment: @OneCricketeer how i could use this solution and pass arguments with script too like:
pyspark < script.py 'args1' 'args2' 'args'

Comment: @Leo It's just `spark-submit script.py arg1 arg2`... There's no reason to use the REPL to run a script like this

Answer (score 3):

Existing answers are right (that is use `spark-submit`), but some of us might want to just get started with a sparkSession object like in pyspark.

So in the pySpark script to be run first add:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master('yarn') \
    .appName('pythonSpark') \
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
```

Then use `spark.conf.set('conf_name', 'conf_value')` to set any configuration like executor cores, memory, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Spark environment provides a command to execute the application file, be it in Scala or Java(need a Jar format), Python and R programming file.
The command is,

`$ spark-submit --master <url> <SCRIPTNAME>.py`.

I'm running spark in windows 64bit architecture system with JDK 1.8 version.

P.S find a screenshot of my terminal window.
[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akRg5.png)